# Select everything except iframe by using $(this) and .not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wrote this code and it is working properly:

HTML:

```
<div class="service-box">
  <!--Services Title 1-->
  <h3>WordPress installation</h3>
  <!--Content for title 1-->
  <div class="service-content">
   <!--Your youtube service video iframe code-->
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R7hHfoffIM4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <!--Your service description-->
    <p>I am offering services like:</p> 
    <p>WordPress installation to your already purchased domain and hosting.</p>
    <p>Also I am able to create subdomain and install wordpress on it.</p>
    <p>If You need me to make a WP backup, I can do that for You.</p>
    <p>In case that You need me to restore your website from my previously made backup I am here for You.</p>      
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.service-box', function(){                    
    $('#siteOverlay').addClass('overlay-active');
    $('#popupWindow').addClass('service-active');
    $('#popupWindow #contentBox').html($(this).html());   //I will change this line
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```

Then I try to select everything except IFRAME tag like this:

```
 $('#popupWindow #contentBox').html($(this).not($('iframe')).html());
```

or like this:

```
$('#popupWindow #contentBox').html($(this).not('iframe').html());
```

and it doesn't work.
I have also tried to use:not selector in all combinations like this:

```
$('#popupWindow #contentBox').html($(this:not).html());
```

Nothing is working.  Is there anyone who knows the answer to this?
Thanks!

Comment: none of your attempts even make sense.... `this` is the `.service-box` that was clicked. It isn't an iframe, nor is it a collection that contains an iframe, therefore you cannot filter an iframe from it.

Comment: interesting. what is happening? do you get any result or is it just empty or does it throw an exception? Try `document` instead of `this`. What I do not yet fully understand, is the popupWindow not a part of the same document that you're attempting to get the popup content from?

Comment: @putvande's answer was close, simply needed .clone() instead of .html()

Comment: show your markup if you can. or a jsfiddle. where are those `iframe`s nested that you even need to exclude them?

Comment: Please provide some HTML because as Kevin B points out, it is n't clear what you're after.

Comment: I have added HTML.  I am taking content and putting it into popup window. Therefore I use .html to remove old content from popup and place new content in it.  I have 19 services-boxe-s.

Comment: Thanks guys, Kevin has answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove the iframe from the html of the clicked element, not from the clicked element itself. so.... you'll have to clone it and remove it from the clone, then append it.

```
var clone = $(this).clone();
clone.find('iframe').remove();
$('#popupWindow #contentBox').html(clone.contents());
```

Comment: Perhaps just eliminate the `#popupWindow` as it would be faster?

Comment: yes, that would be a good idea. but i rather focus on the problem

Comment: This is what I have been looking for. Now I need to study this thorough to understand it better. Thank You Kevin.

Comment: Thanks for advice Mark!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var clone = $(this).clone();
clone.find('iframe').remove();
$('#contentBox').empty().append(clone);
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.service-box', function() {
  $('#siteOverlay').addClass('overlay-active');
  $('#popupWindow').addClass('service-active');
  var clone = $(this).clone();
  clone.find('iframe').remove();
  $('#contentBox').empty().append(clone);
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```

```css
#siteOverlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#siteOverlay.overlay-active {
  display: block;
}

#popupWindow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#contentBox {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service-box">
  <!--Services Title 1-->
  <h3>WordPress installation</h3>
  <!--Content for title 1-->
  <div class="service-content">
    <!--Your youtube service video iframe code-->
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R7hHfoffIM4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <!--Your service description-->
    <p>I am offering services like:</p>
    <p>WordPress installation to your already purchased domain and hosting.</p>
    <p>Also I am able to create subdomain and install wordpress on it.</p>
    <p>If You need me to make a WP backup, I can do that for You.</p>
    <p>In case that You need me to restore your website from my previously made backup I am here for You.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="siteOverlay">
  <div id="popupWindow">
    <div id="contentBox"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You Patrick for your effort!  Kevin B. has already answered my question.